# REST API authorization with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to secure my APIs using `@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ADMIN')")` For this purpose, I have implemented a `UserDetailsService` to get the data from database. And If you try to access any secured API, it shows you a default login form.

The code that I am folllowing is this https://github.com/TechPrimers/spring-security-example

My project is successfully running. But it does not show a login form when I am trying to access my secured API in browser.

Also, I want to be able to access REST API both with and without authorization header.

This documentation

https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/security-rest-basic-auth-example/

uses `InMemoryAuthentication` and it is also able to access API both using browser and Postman. Meanwhile, I am taking the data from my database. How can I customize my implementation in such a way so it can work for both the browser and Postman?

Comment: I am following the tutorial whose link I have mentioned. I have done as it is. Everything is working even my secured api is being not accessed without login. The only error is its not showing the login form.

Answer (score 0):

The code below would require a form for anything matching the wildcard. The slash at the start is required in the antMatcher

```
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .csrf().disable()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/**/secured/**")
                    .authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .httpBasic();
        }
```

Comment: sorry no, csrf is separate you can keep that I will edit my answer

Comment: Still gives me the same error ''access is denied'' :(

Comment: The anyrequest.permitall() can be kept too if you want, it will explicitly allow other routes that don't match the antMatcher and is clearer. Without it, other requests will implicitly be allowed because I have only specified those routes that should be secured. So both would work

Comment: The HttpSecurity security chain should now be correct as I have a working example locally. I think your issue is now within the CustomUserDetailsService. Try adding additional logging or use the debugger to check whether optionalUsers is empty or getAuthorities returns an empty collection